# '[Error] Unable to find or read "package.json" in the CWD. The "release-react" command must be executed in a React Native project folder.'

Tags: json, shell, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I've been getting this error while trying to create a script file to automate a little of the codePush deployment process.

Looking at all the information I could find online wasn't helping - In the script I echo'd the PWD to see that I am running the `code-push release-react` command from the correct location in my .sh file, I am including `react-native` as a package dependency in my `package.json`. Everything looked fine, but I was still getting the error.

Since I found the issue but couldn't find anything online to point to what the problem was, I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon playing with the scripts in my `package.json` I tried running npm install again to make sure everything was setup properly when I get an error that actually showed me my issue.

The problem was the JSON in my `package.json` had become corrupted - the syntax wasn't spot on. I had started playing with the json in the file and forgot to revert the changes I made when I finished and had an extra comma.

Now that almost a whole day is gone, I can get back to work.